# what BLE data type should i use for sending short actions like jumps?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I wish to send data from one phone to another by BLE characteristic.
I want to notify the other side each time a jump was made.
For example, the receiving device has the Mario game and should be notified on each jump.

I've thought to use jumps counter, so the receiving side will be able to notice counter increases.

What do you think is the best way to send notify of short action like jump? what data type to use?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I want to communicate with bluetooth i keep the data being transmitted as simple as possible, so if you want to notify the other phone that Mario is jumping, define a standard int value for the jumps and send it every time Mario jumps, the counting you can do on the receiving phone, this way you keep the communication slightly simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the BLE protocol stack from bottom to top, the sending device could be: Master at Link Layer, Central at GAP layer and Client at GATT layer. On the other side, the receiving device could be Slave at Linke Layer, Peripheral at GAP and Server at GATT, the GATT database could just contain a single Characteristic, its descriptor and the Service declaration. Then, the GATT Client can just write or indicate a characteristic (a uint seems OK to me) on the GATT server to indicate that a Mario should jump.

While virtually all phones can be GAP Central, not all can be Peripheral. See [here](https://github.com/WebBluetoothCG/ble-test-peripheral-android) for an example of an app simulating a peripheral device; and [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothLeGatt/) for an app being the Central device.